# Integrating the inverse gamma probability distribution function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am stuck trying to integrate the inverse gamma random variable. Since it is a PDF, it should integrate to $1$. Here is my attempt:

\begin{align}
    \int_0^{\infty}f_X(x) = \int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha}(\dfrac{1}{x})^{\alpha+1}e^{\dfrac{-1}{\beta x}}dx
\end{align}

By substitution: $u = \dfrac{1}{x}$ and $du = \dfrac{-1}{x^2}dx$. Hence $dx = -x^2du$. Going back to the integral:

\begin{align}
    \int_0^{\infty}f_X(x) = \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha}\int_0^{\infty}u^{\alpha-1}\dfrac{1}{x^2}e^{\dfrac{-u}{\beta}}(-x^2)du \\
    \int_0^{\infty}f_X(x) = \dfrac{-1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha}\int_0^{\infty}u^{\alpha-1}e^{\dfrac{-u}{\beta}}du \\
\end{align}

Now, $\int_0^{\infty}u^{\alpha-1}e^{\dfrac{-u}{\beta}}du$ is simply the kernel or a regular gamma distribution, so $\int_0^{\infty}u^{\alpha-1}e^{\dfrac{-u}{\beta}}du = \Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha}$. Then:
\begin{align}
    \int_0^{\infty}f_X(x) = \dfrac{-1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha}\int_0^{\infty}u^{\alpha-1}e^{\dfrac{-u}{\beta}}du = \dfrac{-1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha = -1 \\
\end{align}

It was obviously supposed to be equal to $1$ and not $-1$, but despite spending hours at it, I cannot seem to find where is my mistake.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $u$ goes from $\infty$ to $0$.  When you flip these, you get the required factor of $-1$.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thank you very much!